# Place texts in specifics positions inside a responsive div with background image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a react app and I'm trying to place texts in specific positions in a responsive div with background image. When I change the device height/width or zoom in the texts wont stay in the correct place. The whole chart below is my background.

I've tried setting position relative and fixed in the Texts, with Top and Left in % that matched the gray rectangles in my css.

The whole component

```
  <Modal.Body>
    <Row className="textBodyHeader">
      <Col>
        <h6>PETR4, PETROBRAS PN N2 4,17</h6>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <FormInternoCompraAgendada />
      </Col>

      <Col className="colGrafico">
        <div class="valorTotalGrafico">26,50</div>
        <div class="GainDisparoGrafico">26,50</div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Modal.Body>
```

The div with background image from code above

```
<Col className="colGrafico">
        <div class="valorTotalGrafico">26,50</div>
        <div class="GainDisparoGrafico">26,50</div>
      </Col>
```

My CSS

```
.colGrafico {
  background-image: url("../img/compraAgendada.PNG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center center;
}

.valorTotalGrafico {
  color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55%;
  left: 97.5%;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.GainDisparoGrafico {
  color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 33.3%;
  left: 130%;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

The main component.

[image]

I expect five texts (26,50) in these gray boxes in this div.

[image]

Comment: In general this is difficlut with a background image as they are no responsive in the same way as normal elements - use and **actual** image - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulie_D! I made changes based on your code with a fixed div with text in each gray rectangle. I used display flex with vertical and horizontal alignment in each one.